# Why is 也 used for negation in 你也配?

Tags: grammar, negation

[image]

I haven't seen 也 used on its own for negation yet - is it a popular use? How does it work? Could you give more examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

也 means even

你**也**配? (**even** you are worthy?) is a rhetorical question, it is in fact, a statement for "你不配" (you are not worthy)

(*the standard hasn't sunk so low that even people like you are worthy/ qualified*)

你配嗎? (are you worthy/qualified?) is another way to ask this rhetorical question. It too means  "你不配" (you are not worthy)

More example:

三歲小孩也能當兵? (even a 3-year-old child can be a soldier?) is a rhetorical question, the answer/ statement is "of course a 3-year-old child can't be a soldier"

Comment: Thank you for the examples, very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

> a. 你不配。
> b. 你也配？
> c. 你也配！

All of the above express the same meaning: you are not qualified (for something or to do something). Of course sentence a. is the most straightforward option. I'd say sentences b. and c. are **rhetorical** (hence the lack of negation), with sentence c. being much stronger than b., bordering on **irony**. We should not look at sentence c. as a **statement** (陳述句), but an **interjection** (感嘆句).

Answer (score 2):

The dialogue would make better understanding if a question mark is included, as, 你也配？, which actually questions someone's "qualification or worthiness" rather than affirming it.

Saying, 你也配？ ( "You are qualified / worthy"?) rather than, say, "你配吗"?, ("Are you qualified / worthy"?) which unmistakably questions the worthiness, is what's called a "positive irony", a positive statement which carries a sarcastic implication of a negative meaning.

Your question, "Why is 也 used for negation of 你也配?"

也 here would mean "could also be considered as being..."

Thus 你也配? would be read in extended form as "You could also be considered as being qualified / worthy"?, which actually reinforces the positive ironic effect.

Actually without the 也 as "你配?" works just as well in the dialogue in question. I suppose the 也 is also for dialectic emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

In here, 也 means "too", or "also".

For example - 那些人都是英雄. (你算老幾,) 你也配!? "All those people are heroes. Who the hell you are that thinking of yourself qualifies as one too!?"

你也配 is a frequently used phrase when one wants to show contempt for somebody's qualification/capability to be a character of high quality through a negative tune of questioning.

Another example - 她是個知書達理的大美人. 你也配!? "She is a classy lady with rarely seen beauty. Do you also have the qualities to be one!?

Answer (score 0):

This use of 也 is for ***emphasis***.  Other examples:

> 一点儿也不累。

> 手都破了也不知道。